# Application not working on iis 7 windows server 2012r2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

In windows server 2012r2 I have installed the iis7 and host the ASP.NET MVC application but domain is still not reachable or accessble the files. irt is showing "This site can't be reach".

I have tried with another domain mapped with the same server ip but issue is still remain same.

Comment: Have you updated the dns A record to point the domain to the hosting server up?

Comment: yes I have pointed this ip 52.66.211.23 with A record.

Comment: https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx Check if your domain is pointing to correct IP address. Also, ensure you have added the domain binding in your IIS website

Comment: Yes! I have checked and it has been pointed on correct ip. There is no issue on domain. I am doing something wrong on server because when I have tried to map with another server it will working fine.

Comment: Run a Binding Diagnostics report, and see what it says, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html